# Is there a way to recover the original electrum seed from the encrypted one?

Tags: electrum, lost-bitcoins, seed

So I accidentally lost my electrum seed and password, but I still have the wallet file, so I was wondering if there is a way to recover the original seed from the encrypted one?

I think my password might have been pretty short in which case brute forcing it might work, is there any software that can do this?

Comment: Would an answer to this question still be helpful to you? If so, what do you remember about your password? How short? Which characters did you use (upper/lower/digits/symbols/etc.)?

Comment: I don't remember too much, it was probably around 10ish digits in length that's about it.

Comment: Do you literally mean digits, as in all 10 characters of your password were numerals (0-9), or do you mean 10 characters of unknown type (letters/numerals/etc.)? 10 *digits* would be fairly easy to brute-force, however 10 *letters* would be much more difficult/expensive (1-2 years on a typical home PC, or a couple thousand USD via a cloud provider, or possibly much more depending if there are capitals/digits in the mix too).